# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - ( 1 - x )^n}{x} \, dx$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - (1 - x)^n}{x} \, dx \ ?$$

Comment: Hint: $$ \frac{1 - (1-x)^n}{x} = \frac{1-(1-x)^n}{1-(1-x)} = 1 + (1-x) + \cdots + (1-x)^{n-1}, $$ if $n$ is a positive integer. Can you integrate each term?

Comment: @SangchulLee: That should be an answer rather than a comment

Comment: @SangchulLee. Put it as an answer, for sure !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the substitution $u = 1-x$, you see that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-u^n}{1-u} \, du. $$

Now you can invoke the following famous algebra:

$$ 1 + u + \cdots + u^{n-1} = \frac{1-u^n}{1-u}. $$

Then you can integrate term-wise to obtain that the answer is the $n$-th harmonic number:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-u^n}{1-u} \, du = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}. $$

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: Expand the top and simplify to get a power series (polynomial in this case) and then integrate term by term.

Comment: Could be long, isn't it ?

Comment: Sure is. I've seen this question some where in a problem book a long time ago, and there was a special technique like the use of Gamma or Beta function.